# VBA Workbook.close function: Cannot make this work within required location

Tags: .net, vba, excel

I have this code:

```
Sub test()
    Dim wb As String
    Dim wbb As Workbook
    wb =     "C:\xyz.xlsx"
    Set wbb = Workbooks.Open(wb)
    MsgBox ("testing")
    wbb.Close
End Sub
```

The above does the job just **fine**.
Workbook closes **as expected**

This code however, **does not** seem to work. But to me it looks **identical** in relation to the workbooks.close function. Can someone please advise why this throws the error "Run-time error '1004': **Application-defined or object-defined error**"

```
Sub filesTest(folder, dex)
Dim wb As String
Dim wbb As Workbook
Dim dat
Dim dat2
Dim dat3
Dim dat4

wb = "xyz.xlsm"
    For Each file In folder.Files
        If file.Name Like "*.xlsm" Then
            If InStr(file.Name, "~$") = 0 Then
            'sendFile (file.Name)
                Set wbb = Workbooks.Open(file)
                Worksheets("Sheet 1").Select
               dat = Range("F11")
                Worksheets("Sheet 2").Select
                dat2 = Range("C54")
                dat3 = Range("D54")
                dat4 = Range("E54")
               wbb.Close
            Workbooks(wb).Activate
            Range("B" & dex) = dat
            Range("C" & dex) = dat2
            Range("D" & dex) = dat3
            Range("E" & dex) = dat4
            End If
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

I have attempted to move the location of the wbb.close but this does not seem to help at all.

I have also attempted to use an alternative "Activeworkbook.close false" and variations on this with exactly the same error message appearing.

I have also confirmed Set wbb = Workbooks.Open(**file**) <-- that the file variable has the same format as the code in the test block

Any help would be much appreciated,

Thank you.

Comment: On which line does the error actually occur?

Comment: So the error comes up on the screen. Click 'debug' and it highlights the line **wbb.Close**. I will add- Following this script ending after the error. A box prompts me to close the spreadsheet i was attempting to close. So it does seem to be getting somewhere?

Comment: Is there any code in the `Workbook_Open` event of the workbook that causes the problem?

Comment: the workbooks.open(file) section seems to work perfectly. Is this what you are referring to? Thank you for your advice.

Comment: No, I mean is there code in the workbook you are opening (I note they are all macro files) that runs automatically when you open it? Try adding: `Application.EnableEvents = False` before the `Workbooks.Open` line and  `Application.EnableEvents = True` immediately after opening it.

Comment: There is code there. I thought you had cracked it after reading your logic - it made sense. Unfortunately editing the code to show this    Application.EnableEvents = False
                    Set wbb = Workbooks.Open(file)
                    Application.EnableEvents = True still leads to the same error on wbb.close :/

Comment: Does this code fail on all your workbooks or just some of them? (there isn't actually anything wrong with the code itself)

Comment: RORY YOU ARE A G. **thank you!** I simply left application.enableevents as false until after the wbb was closed. and then avctivated. This works!! Is this simply due to some code within the other workbooks running?

Comment: Also is this safe to leave application.enableEvents as false for a longer period than you originally suggested?

Comment: Maybe someone could post an answer....? (@Rory)

Comment: Unless you want event code to run, it is safe to disable it for longer as long as you **ensure** it is turned back on again. You could also simply skip selecting sheets - it appears that that may be running code that causes your code to fail.

Answer (score 1):

This is the solution:

```
Sub filesTest(folder, dex)
Dim wb As String
Dim wbb As Workbook
Dim dat
Dim dat2
Dim dat3
Dim dat4

wb = "xyz.xlsm"
    For Each file In folder.Files
        If file.Name Like "*.xlsm" Then
            If InStr(file.Name, "~$") = 0 Then
        'sendFile (file.Name)
application.enableevents = false
                Set wbb = Workbooks.Open(file)
                Worksheets("Sheet 1").Select
               dat = Range("F11")
                Worksheets("Sheet 2").Select
                dat2 = Range("C54")
                dat3 = Range("D54")
                dat4 = Range("E54")
               wbb.Close
application.enableevents = true
             Workbooks(wb).Activate
            Range("B" & dex) = dat
            Range("C" & dex) = dat2
            Range("D" & dex) = dat3
            Range("E" & dex) = dat4
            End If
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This may not solve the issue, but I think part of the problem is the multiple workbooks, without explicit references in your `Range`.  It's worth pointing out, and is too long for a comment.

Try using the below:

```
Sub filesTest(folder, dex)
Dim wb      As String
Dim wbb     As Workbook
Dim dat, dat2, dat3, dat4

wb = "xyz.xlsm"
For Each file In folder.Files
    If file.Name Like "*.xlsm" Then
        If InStr(file.Name, "~$") = 0 Then
            'sendFile (file.Name)
            Set wbb = Workbooks.Open(file)
            With wbb
                dat = .Worksheets("Sheet 1").Range("F11")
                dat2 = .Worksheets("Sheet 2").Range("C54")
                dat3 = .Worksheets("Sheet 2").Range("D54")
                dat4 = .Worksheets("Sheet 2").Range("E54")
                .Close
            End With

            With Workbooks(wb)
                .Range("B" & dex) = dat
                .Range("C" & dex) = dat2
                .Range("D" & dex) = dat3
                .Range("E" & dex) = dat4
            End With
        End If
    End If
Next
End Sub
```

What I did was used `With` to help explicitly state where the ranges being used are.  That might help, but if not, let me know.

Comment: Thank you for this, this has shown me the correct way to format my code. However, the application enable events flag was to be set for solution

Comment: @dazedAndConfused - Gotta love it when it's some tertiary code doing it, and not your own :P.  Glad you got it figured out!  But yes, I suggest really looking at the above and seeing how I [removed `.Select` so you can work directly with your data](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba-macros), and also explicitly tell each `Range` what sheet it's to be from (same would go for using `.Cells()`, `.Rows()`, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

It appears you have event code running in the open event and/or sheet activate events, so you can disable that using `EnableEvents`. There's also a lot of unnecessary selecting:

```
Sub filesTest(folder, dex)
Dim wb As String
Dim wbb As Workbook
Dim dat
Dim dat2
Dim dat3
Dim dat4

On Error Goto clean_up
wb = "xyz.xlsm"
    Application.Enableevents = False
    For Each file In folder.Files
        If file.Name Like "*.xlsm" Then
            If InStr(file.Name, "~$") = 0 Then
            'sendFile (file.Name)
                Set wbb = Workbooks.Open(file)

               dat = wbb.Worksheets("Sheet 1").Range("F11").Value
               With wbb.Worksheets("Sheet 2")
                  dat2 = .Range("C54").Value
                  dat3 = .Range("D54").Value
                  dat4 = .Range("E54").Value
               End With
               wbb.Close
            Workbooks(wb).Activate
            Range("B" & dex) = dat
            Range("C" & dex) = dat2
            Range("D" & dex) = dat3
            Range("E" & dex) = dat4
            End If
        End If
    Next

clean_up:
    Application.Enableevents = True
End Sub
```